# PHP solution to do Google federated login easily?

Tags: php, federated-identity

I see stackoverflow's login system and love the simplicity of clicking one button to log in using Google gmail account.

Is there something available for PHP? I know there's solutions out there for Django and others. But would like a PHP solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to is actually just OpenID.

Take a look at this post: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581 [or similar](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+openid).

Comment: @Scott It looks like the [PHP OpenID library](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled) that @GSto mentioned will simplify things for you.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [PHP OpenID library](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled). This should take care of most of it for you, and comes in PHP4 & 5 flavors.